# Why TinyMCE text is not assign in PHP variable

Tags: php, jquery, html

I am trying to assign TinyMCE text editor value to my PHP variable but it's not working properly, when I first try to upload information to the MYSQL database with the empty table it stored the data but when I try to store some more data then TinyMCE don't pass the value to PHP variable, I am not getting it that why its happing..

```
<!--this is my form -->

<form action=""  enctype="multipart/form-data" id="fupForm">
    <div class="col-md-12">
        <div class="post" style="border: none">
            <div class="row">
                <div class="col-md-2 post-date">
                    <div class="day">
                        <?php echo $date_day; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="month">
                        <?php echo $date_month; ?>
                    </div>
                    <div class="year">
                        <?php echo $date_year; ?>
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-7 post-title">
                    <a href="#">
                        <div class="form-group">
                            <label for="postTitle">Title*</label>
                            <input type="text" style="border-color:#D07420;" class="form-control form-control-sm" id="InputTitle" aria-describedby="InputTitle" placeholder="Title" name="InputTitle">
                        </div>
                    </a>
                    <p>Written by:
                        <span>
                            <?php echo $user_name; ?>
                        </span>
                    </p>
                </div>
                <div class="col-md-3 col-xs-6 profile-picture"> <img src="../../img/profile-pic/pem_profile_imge/<?php echo $user_image; ?>" class="rounded-circle " alt="profie iamge "> </div>
            </div>
            <a href="#">
                <div class="form-group">
                    <label for="fileUpload">chose your status photo*</label>
                    <input type="file" style="border-color:#D07420;" class="form-control-file" id="postPicture" name="postPicture">
                </div><img src="../../img/post_iamge/default_post_image.png" alt="Post Image" class="img-responsive" id="previe_post_img">
            </a>
            <div class="form-group">
                <label for="writePost">write your post*</label>
                <textarea id="myTextArea"  class="mceEditor textarea_class" name="myTextArea"></textarea>

            </div>

            <button type="submit" class="btn btn-secondary submitBtn" id="submit_post" style="margin-top:20px">Submit your post</button>
        </div>
    </div>
</form>


<script>

    //this is my jquery

    //          form submission here
    $(document).ready(function () {
        $("#fupForm").on('submit', function (e) {
            e.preventDefault();

            var post_title = $('#InputTitle').val();
            var post_image = $('#postPicture').val();
            var post_data = (tinyMCE.get('myTextArea').getContent());

            if (post_title.trim() == '') {
                alert('Please write Title  of  your Post.');
                $('#InputTitle').focus();
                return false;
            } else if (post_image == "") {
                alert('Please select a valid  Post image (JPEG/JPG/PNG).');
                return false;
            } else if (post_data.trim() == '' || post_data.length < 30) {
                alert('Please write somthing in your Post. atleast 30 charachters');
                $('#myTextArea').focus();
                return false;
            } else {
                $.ajax({
                    type: 'POST',
                    url: '../interfaces/write_post.php',
                    data: new FormData(this),
                    contentType: false,
                    cache: false,
                    processData: false,
                    beforeSend: function () {
                        $('.submitBtn').attr("disabled", "disabled");
                        $('#fupForm').css("opacity", ".5");
                    },
                    success: function (msg) {
                        window.console.log(msg);
                        $('.statusMsg').html('');
                        if (msg == 'ok') {
                            $('#fupForm')[0].reset();
                            $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#34A853">Form data submitted successfully.</span>');
                        } else {
                            $('.statusMsg').html('<span style="font-size:18px;color:#EA4335">Some problem occurred, please try again.</span>');
                        }
                        $('#fupForm').css("opacity", "");
                        $(".submitBtn").removeAttr("disabled");
                    }
                });

            }

        });
    });
</script>





//PHP code for form submission 

<?php
ob_start();
session_start();
require_once( '../../inc/db-connect.php' );

if (!isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    header('location:http:../index.php');
}

if (isset($_SESSION['username'])) {
    $session_userID = $_SESSION['userid'];
    $session_ROLE = $_SESSION['role'];
}



if (!empty($_POST['InputTitle']) || !empty($_POST['myTextArea']) || !empty($_FILES['postPicture']['name'])) {

    $uploadedFile = '';
    $date = $post_id = time();
    $InputTitle = $_POST['InputTitle'];
    $myTextArea = $_POST["myTextArea"];



    //  image upload on the server
    if (!empty($_FILES["postPicture"]["type"])) {
        $fileName = $post_id . '_' . $_FILES['postPicture']['name'];
        $valid_extensions = array("jpeg", "jpg", "png");
        $temporary = explode(".", $_FILES["postPicture"]["name"]);
        $file_extension = end($temporary);
        if (( ( $_FILES["postPicture"]["type"] == "image/png" ) || ( $_FILES["postPicture"]["type"] == "image/jpg" ) || ( $_FILES["postPicture"]["type"] == "image/jpeg" ) ) && in_array($file_extension, $valid_extensions)) {
            $sourcePath = $_FILES['postPicture']['tmp_name'];
            $targetPath = "../../img/post_iamge/" . $fileName;
            if (move_uploaded_file($sourcePath, $targetPath)) {
                $uploadedFile = $fileName;
            }
        }

        $query_insert = "INSERT INTO `post` (`post_serial_num`, `post_id`, `user_id`, `date`, `title`, `post_image`, `post_data`, `view`, `status`) VALUES (NULL, '$post_id', '$session_userID', '$date', '$InputTitle', '$uploadedFile', '$myTextArea', NULL, 'unpublish');";

        $query_insert .= "INSERT INTO `objection_report` (`sNo`, `obj_post_id`, `obj_comment_id`, `obj_user_id`, `obj_user_role`, `obj_title`, `obj_message`, `obj_status`, `obj_admin_aprove`) VALUES (NULL, '$post_id', NULL, '$session_userID', '$session_ROLE', NULL, NULL, 'unpublish', 'no');";
    }

    if (mysqli_multi_query($con, $query_insert)) {
        echo "ok";
    } else {
        echo "error";
    }
}

<!--addition important information-->
Although data is being saved in my database with empty space
```

Comment: Look for the method in docs that refreshes content back to the textarea...then try that before setting `FormData`

Comment: sorry, sir, I forget to write method here in the question but in the programming document, the method I used is "post"

Comment: Right...that would be expected and can see using `$_POST` in php

Comment: thanx sir, but the problem is still there and I am not getting why its happing

Comment: no one has the solution for this problem